# Unable to deploy phoenix with edeliver which throws an compile_env/4 error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver

I am trying to deploy the app with edeliver. However during the .... I get the following error. Not sure what is it actually means. Though in the dev environment it works fine.

1. mix compile - Successful
2. iex -S mix phx.server - I can serve the api and no issues.
3. Guardian can also authenticate the JWT token

So puzzled about deployment.

**Building the code for edeliver**

```
mix edeliver build release --verbose
```

**Error:**

```elixir
    == Compilation error in file lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex ==
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Application."MACRO-compile_env"/4    
        
        The following arguments were given to Application."MACRO-compile_env"/4:
        
            # 1
            #Macro.Env<aliases: [], context: nil, context_modules: [Pxf.Auth.Guardian], file: "/tmp/edeliver/pxf/builds/lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex", function: nil, functions: [{Kernel, [!=: 2, !==: 2, *: 2, +: 1, +: 2, ++: 2, -: 1, -: 2, --: 2, /: 2, <: 2, <=: 2, ==: 2, ===: 2, =~: 2, >: 2, >=: 2, abs: 1, apply: 2, apply: 3, binary_part: 3, bit_size: 1, byte_size: 1, ceil: 1, div: 2, elem: 2, exit: 1, floor: 1, function_exported?: 3, get_and_update_in: 3, get_in: 2, hd: 1, inspect: 1, inspect: 2, is_atom: 1, is_binary: 1, is_bitstring: 1, is_boolean: 1, is_float: 1, is_function: 1, is_function: 2, ...]}], lexical_tracker: #PID<0.647.0>, line: 2, macro_aliases: [], macros: [{Kernel, [!: 1, &&: 2, ..: 2, ..//: 3, <>: 2, @: 1, alias!: 1, and: 2, binding: 0, binding: 1, def: 1, def: 2, defdelegate: 2, defexception: 1, defguard: 1, defguardp: 1, defimpl: 2, defimpl: 3, defmacro: 1, defmacro: 2, defmacrop: 1, defmacrop: 2, defmodule: 2, defoverridable: 1, defp: 1, defp: 2, defprotocol: 2, defstruct: 1, destructure: 2, get_and_update_in: 2, if: 2, in: 2, is_exception: 1, is_exception: 2, is_nil: 1, is_struct: 1, is_struct: 2, ...]}], module: Pxf.Auth.Guardian, requires: [Application, Guardian, Kernel, Kernel.Typespec], ...>
        
            # 2
            {:the_otp_app, [line: 2, counter: {Pxf.Auth.Guardian, 2}], Guardian}
        
            # 3
            [{:__MODULE__, [line: 2, counter: {Pxf.Auth.Guardian, 2}], Guardian}, :permissions]
        
            # 4
            nil
        
        (elixir 1.12.2) lib/application.ex:505: Application."MACRO-compile_env"/4
        (elixir 1.12.2) expanding macro: Application.compile_env/2
        lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex:2: Pxf.Auth.Guardian (module)
        (elixir 1.12.2) expanding macro: Kernel.||/2
        lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex:2: Pxf.Auth.Guardian (module)
        (elixir 1.12.2) expanding macro: Kernel.@/1
        lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex:2: Pxf.Auth.Guardian (module)
        (guardian 2.3.1) expanding macro: Guardian.__using__/1
```

This is a previous project which was build with Phoenix 1.3.2 and I've migrated to Phoenix 1.6.15.

I'm new to this edeliver deployment and not sure whether it is the current way to push the code to the server?

Comment: The release is compiled in `prod` and it seems your `prod.exs` has a malformed definition for what get read in `lib/pxf/auth/guardian.ex` via `Application.compile_env/3`.

Comment: My `prod.exs` seems to look good with just the Endpoint`import Config

config :pixerf, PixerfWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  load_from_system_env: true,
  url: [host: "localhost", port: 4000],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  server: true,
  code_reloader: false

# Do not print debug messages in production
config :logger, level: :info`

Guardian config seems to be correct as well.

Comment: Still same error. I have all my configuration in the `runtime.exs` file. Isn’t that right?

Comment: `Application.compile_env/3` cannot read `runtime.exs` for obvious reasons.

Comment: I don’t see any compile_env call in my code during runtime.